# How to copy, paste, cut in FastColoredTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need three functions: Copy, Paste, Cut ,

For a [FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting).. so far with my methods, the job is done but afterwards,

the cursor's position get changed and I got no clue on how to keep it where it

was before.

Here's my methods:

```
    private void OnMouseMenuCut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sPoint = rtbScript.SelectionStart;
        var ePoint = rtbScript.SelectionLength;

        var text = rtbScript.SelectedText;
        rtbScript.Text = rtbScript.Text.Remove(sPoint, ePoint);

        Clipboard.SetText(text.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
        rtbScript.Text = rtbScript.Text.Insert(sPoint, text);
    }

    private void OnMouseMenuCopy(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbScript.SelectedText)) return;
        Clipboard.SetText(rtbScript.SelectedText.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));

    }

    private void OnMouseMenuPaste(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Clipboard.ContainsText()) return;
        var index = rtbScript.SelectionStart;

        rtbScript.Text = rtbScript.Text.Insert(index, Clipboard.GetText());
    }
```

Also, If there's a better way to do those functions, please post..

Thanks!

Comment: Why not store it and later restore it? the cursor is always at SelectionStart.

Comment: I tried that already, it still went to another place. Also I forgot to mention that im using the customized [FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Well in that case I can't hep you. You will have to dig into the code..

Comment: Your solution worked! I thought that the functions are different.. could you please restore it so I'll be able to mark it as the selected answer? thanks!!

Comment: done. If you want to edit out the commented lines etc feel free to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a RichTextBox your code has more issues than loosing the Cursor position, It also looses all formatting! Here are versions that should work better:

```
    private void OnMouseMenuCut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sPoint = rtbScript.SelectionStart;
        var text = rtbScript.SelectedText;

        rtbScript.Cut();

        Clipboard.SetText(text.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
        rtbScript.SelectionStart = sPoint;
    }

    private void OnMouseMenuCopy(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbScript.SelectedText)) return;
        Clipboard.SetText(rtbScript.SelectedText.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
    }

    private void OnMouseMenuPaste(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Clipboard.ContainsText()) return;
        var index = rtbScript.SelectionStart;

        rtbScript.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();
        rtbScript.SelectionStart = index + Clipboard.GetText().Length;
    }
```

Note: You must never change the Text property of a RTB or else you will mess up the formating!

Since you wrote that this also works with your `FastColoredTextBox` I have undeleted the solution..

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of FCTB, these methods already exist inside the FCTB.cs file.  They just need to be linked up.